# ERC20Capped: Immutable variables cannot be read during contract creation time, which means they cannot be read in the constructor OpenZeppelin 4

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, openzeppelin

When I try to mint inside of constructor using `ERC20Capped` from OpenZeppelin 4 like

```
contract SomeERC20 is ERC20Capped {

    constructor (
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 cap,
        uint256 initialBalance
    )
        ERC20(name, symbol)
        ERC20Capped(cap)
    {
        _mint(_msgSender(), initialBalance);
    }
}
```

the error

`Immutable variables cannot be read during contract creation time, which means they cannot be read in the constructor or any function or modifier called from it`

appears.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cap is immutable in `ERC20Capped` thus it cannot be read during the mint process in the constructor. It was done on purpose to lower gas costs. You can either mint outside of the constructor or use the `_mint` function from common `ERC20` like this

```
contract SomeERC20 is ERC20Capped {

    constructor (
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 cap,
        uint256 initialBalance
    )
        ERC20(name, symbol)
        ERC20Capped(cap)
    {
        require(initialBalance <= cap, "CommonERC20: cap exceeded"); // this is needed to know for sure the cap is not exceded.
        ERC20._mint(_msgSender(), initialBalance);
    }
}
```

It is advised to add a check for the `initialSupply` to be lower than the `cap` The check is originally done in the `_mint` function of `ERC20Capped` but not in the `ERC20` and since you are using the latter the check is omitted.

Comment: strange this comment is not upwoted yet. Made few contracts in autumn 2020, but today in summer 2021 old approaches does not work anymore. And this answer is very helpful. Saves lots of time. I even have time for a beer because of this and hot weather in the summer